# Push notification reached the device but not able to see it in the applicaition

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am using mobilefirst push notification service in my application. I am using rest api to send the message to GCM.

GCM receives and send it back to the mobile device too but in the device I am able to see the push message in the log, but not in alert which is the event source I have registered in my client device.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have received a notification intended for Push.ALL tag. This is a broadcast notification and will not appear within the callback you registered with your Eventsource subscription.

You should use the onMessage callback API, as described in [KnowledgeCenter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html%23onMessage) and [GettingStarted](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/).